# Access value of a variable in a nested class

Tags: c++, class, nested

header file:

```
class A
{
public:        
    void setNumber(unsigned );
    void changeNumber();  
    unsigned result;

    class B
    {
    public:
        void setResult();
        unsigned valorB;
    };

private:                           
    static unsigned number; 
};
```

Implementation file:

```
void A::setNumber(unsigned value)
{
    number = value;
}

void A::changeNumber()
{
    result = number * 5 + 10;
}

void A::B::setResult()
{
    valorB = number + 5;
}
```

How can I access a variable in the internal class? I know how to access the variables of A, but i don't know how i do to access variables of B.

I want to access "valorB".

Comment: Do you get a compiler error with the above code? If so, what is it?

Comment: "undefined reference to A::number"

Comment: I didn't know Argument Dependent Lookup works this way also. I believed it works only for namespaces. Was wondering how `number` can be accessed in different class!

Answer (score 2):

*Declaring* a class is not enough, you need an *instance* of class `B` to access its variables. For example, you can add a declaration of member variable to class `A`, like this:

```
class B
{
public:
    void setResult();
    unsigned valorB;
};
B memberB;
```

Now you can access `valorB` like this:

```
A a;
a.memberB.valorB = 3;
```

The other problem in your code is lack of *definition* of a declared static variable `number`. You need to add this to your CPP:

```
unsigned A::number;
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, because definition of a method `A::B::setResult()` does not require an instance.

Comment: @GregHewgill Indeed, it does not, and it shouldn't need to: `A` to `B` is no more than a namespace, and `A::B::setResult()` provides a definition for a member function that may or may not be called.

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you said, but for some reason when you print the value in valueB apparently is printing "garbage". The value being printed has no relation to what was implemented. Is there a syntax error in the implementation file?

Comment: @tiggares Did you initialize the value that you are printing? Could you edit the question with your updated code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you are getting,

```
undefined reference to A::number
```

the problem is not related to `valorB`. The problem is that you have not provided a definition of `A::number`. Add to your `.cpp` file:

```
unsigned A::number;
```